# Using trait methods in threads

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns, rust

Basically, I'm making a program that's listening to a bunch of ports and that handles incoming packets in different ways. I decide to bundle this code into a Trait:

```
use std::old_io::{TcpStream, TcpListener, Listener, Acceptor, EndOfFile, IoResult};
use std::thread::Thread;

trait Server {
    fn new(port: u16) -> Self;

    fn hostname(&self) -> &String;

    fn initialize(&self) {
        let acceptor = TcpListener::bind(self.hostname().as_slice()).listen().unwrap();
        Thread::spawn(move|| {
            let mut acceptor = acceptor;
            for incoming_stream in acceptor.incoming() {
                match incoming_stream {
                    Ok(stream) => {
                        self.handle_client(stream);
                    },
                    Err(ref e) if e.kind == EndOfFile => break,
                    Err(e) => panic!("Unexpected error: {}", e),
                }
            }
        });
    }

    fn handle_client(&self, stream: TcpStream) -> ();
}

pub struct InternodeServer {
    hostname: String,
}

impl Server for InternodeServer {
    fn new(port: u16) -> InternodeServer {
        let hostname = format!("127.0.0.1:{}", port);
        InternodeServer {
            hostname: hostname,
        }
    }

    fn hostname(&self) -> &String {
        &self.hostname
    }

    fn handle_client(&self, stream: TcpStream) {
        println!("Received connection");
        let mut stream = stream;
        let response = b"Hello\r\n";
        let _ = stream.write_all(response);
        let _ = stream.close_write();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test_server = <InternodeServer as Server>::new(9337);
    test_server.initialize();
}
```

However, this code won't work because you can't send `Self`. This is the error I receive:

```
test.rs:11:9: 11:22 error: the trait `core::marker::Send` is not implemented for the type `Self` [E0277]
test.rs:11         Thread::spawn(move|| {
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.rs:11:9: 11:22 note: `Self` cannot be sent between threads safely
test.rs:11         Thread::spawn(move|| {
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So I also tried making handle_client a static method to avoid self. To do this, I simply changed handle_client to:

```
fn handle_client(stream: TcpStream)
```

And referenced it by doing:

```
Server::handle_client(stream);
```

However, I can't reference InternodeServer's static methods from Server's initialize method. When compiling, I get an error like:

```
test.rs:16:25: 16:46 error: type annotations required: cannot resolve `_ : Server` [E0283]
test.rs:16                         Server::handle_client(stream);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.rs:16:25: 16:46 note: required by `Server::handle_client`
test.rs:16                         Server::handle_client(stream);
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Please reform your code to be a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is right now, it's very hard to compile it to see your error. Also, please add the error you get when you say "&self isn't Thread-safe". On top of all that, your code is inconsistent - you removed `&self` from `handle_client`, but still use it as a method in `initialize`! Showing that you care about your question's quality is the first step to getting quality answers!

Comment: Sir yes sir - the code in question is actually a lot bigger, I just cut out the good parts for the question. I'll update my question and make the above pieces compile.

Comment: Should be better now! Sorry about that. It was late at night :)

Comment: No worries! I'm not trying to be a jerk, more like a lowly janitor, helping to make sure questions are clear and useful to people who come afterwards. ^_^

Comment: Here's a [minimal example of the error](http://is.gd/oZQ0kU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a smaller reproduction of the error:

```
use std::thread::Thread;

trait Server {
    fn initialize(&self) {
        Thread::spawn(move || self.handle_client());
    }

    fn handle_client(&self);
}

fn main() {}
```

The problem is that the argument passed to [`Thread::spawn`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Thread.html#method.spawn) must be [`Send`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html). You are trying to move `self` into the closure, but your trait doesn't guarantee `Send`, so the closure can't be `Send`.

We can attempt to go down that path with `trait Server: Send`, but then we get "cannot infer an appropriate lifetime" errors because `Send` also requires `'static` ([for now](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0458-send-improvements.md)). Also, it seems very strange to *move yourself* into a closure.

Really, I think you want to split up your code. Move `handle_client` into a separate trait and then ensure that implementations of that trait are `Send`:

```
use std::thread::Thread;

trait Server {
    fn initialize<D>(&self, driver: D)
        where D: Driver + Send
    {
        Thread::spawn(move || driver.handle_client());
    }
}

trait Driver {
    fn handle_client(&self);
}

fn main() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that rust will allow you to invoke object methods directly from other thread because "move" closures cannot borrow anything, only move.

So you have to use some kind of inter-thread communication tool, for example, channels:

```
use std::thread::Thread;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender, Receiver, RecvError};
use std::net::{TcpStream, TcpListener};
use std::io::{ErrorKind, Write};

trait Server {
    fn new(port: u16) -> Self;

    fn hostname(&self) -> &String;

    fn initialize(&mut self, _detached: bool) {
        let acceptor = TcpListener::bind(self.hostname().as_slice()).unwrap();
        let server_tx = self.make_pipe();
        Thread::spawn(move|| {
            for incoming_stream in acceptor.incoming() {
                match incoming_stream {
                    Ok(stream) => server_tx.send(Arc::new(Mutex::new(stream))).unwrap(),
                    Err(ref e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::NotConnected => break,
                    Err(e) => panic!("Unexpected error: {}", e),
                }
            }
        });
    }

    fn handle_client(&self, stream: Arc<Mutex<TcpStream>>);
    fn make_pipe(&mut self) -> Sender<Arc<Mutex<TcpStream>>>;
    fn run(&self);
}

pub struct InternodeServer {
    hostname: String,
    client_rx: Option<Receiver<Arc<Mutex<TcpStream>>>>,
}

impl Server for InternodeServer {
    fn new(port: u16) -> InternodeServer {
        let hostname = format!("127.0.0.1:{}", port);
        InternodeServer {
            hostname: hostname,
            client_rx: None,
        }
    }

    fn make_pipe(&mut self) -> Sender<Arc<Mutex<TcpStream>>> {
        let (server_tx, client_rx) = channel();
        self.client_rx = Some(client_rx);
        server_tx
    }

    fn hostname(&self) -> &String {
        &self.hostname
    }

    fn handle_client(&self, stream_arc: Arc<Mutex<TcpStream>>) {
        println!("Received connection");
        let mut stream = stream_arc.lock().unwrap();
        let response = b"Hello\r\n";
        let _ = stream.write_all(response);
        let _ = drop(stream);
    }

    fn run(&self) {
        loop {
            match self.client_rx.as_ref().unwrap().recv() {
                Ok(stream) => self.handle_client(stream),
                Err(RecvError) => break,
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = <InternodeServer as Server>::new(10101);
    s.initialize(false);
    s.run();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This works, but it means I need one thread to look at the socket and another looking at the channel to handle responses. This means I need two threads per socket (or having one thread per socket and have a "listener" thread that checks each channel maybe?). I was hoping for a way where I could keep one thread per socket.

Comment: There are some classic approaches for client/server architectures, for example, multiplexing (one thread + select/poll/kqueue/epoll), master thread accepting connection + one new fresh thread per each incoming connection, or mixed solutions with threads pools. If you really want threading, you should redesign your code somehow, because rust will not let you share &self between threads. I suggest consider Shepmaster's solution with interface splitting.